# Form based on selected menu item

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a sidebar that I dock on the left side of my application.

Now I'm wondering what's the best way to show a form based on the menu option they've selected from my sidebar.

This is basically what I want to do:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/176782-building-an-application-poscash-register-part-one/

On the left is my menu bar, on the right side I want to have a form based on the option clicked on the left.

I have looked into MDI but when I do that I always get a `ControlBox` even though I've disabled it in the child form.

Update: Seems that this works as well:

Looks like you can also create your own user controls to do it:

[User controls](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/176782-building-an-application-poscash-register-part-one/)

Comment: Hi! Please read how to ask questions on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 0):

First create a panel in your form that will hold your current form's contents (add it to the form but leave it empty for now).

```
Panel active = new Panel();
this.Controls.Add(active);
```

Then create a panel containing controls for each form you want to display.

```
Panel firstFormPanel = new Panel();
firstFormPanel.Add(new Button());
Panel secondFormPanel = new Panel();
secondFormPanel.Add(new Button());
```

Now assign which panel you want by default:

```
active = firstFormPanel;
```

Then when you want to change to a new form (click event in sidebar), assign one of the panels to the active panel like so:

```
active.Visible = false;
active = secondFormPanel;
active.Visible = true;
```

Comment: I forgot to add this. I want to show a different form right of my toolbar in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want second wont allow you to access your main form unless its closed.then use this...

```
second_form_name    sfn = new second_form_name();
sfn.ShowDialog();
```

If you want second  allow you to access your main form unless its closed.then use

```
 second_form_name    sfn = new second_form_name();
  sfn.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little example i have of a sidebar from my game im making being able to slide a new submenu into visual range.  I use a timer to control movement and a list of submenus also a index to determine which to show.   as far as i've gotten along theres only one so far so not a prime example.

```
    public List<UserControl> Submenus = new List<UserControl>();
    Multiplayer_Menu MPM;
    enum At { Left, Right }
    At Current = At.Right;
    At Go_to = At.Right;
    int Submenu_Index = 0;
    bool done = false;

    public void Load_Submenus()
    {
        Multiplayer_Menu MM = new Multiplayer_Menu(this);
        MainMenu.Controls.Add(MM);
        MM.Location = new Point(MainMenu.Size.Width, 0);
        MM.Visible = false;
        Submenus.Add(MM);
        PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();
        MainMenu.Controls.Add(PB);
        PB.Location = new Point(MainMenu.Size.Width, 0);
        PB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(924, 736);
        PB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        PB.ImageLocation = "http://www.taloreal.com/Earth%20Rotation/Rotating.gif";
        PB.Visible = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Load_Submenus();
    }

    public void MML_Multiplayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Submenus[Submenu_Index].Visible = false;
        if (Current == At.Left)
            Go_to = At.Right;
        if (Current == At.Right)
            Go_to = At.Left;
        ShowHideMenus.Enabled = true;
        Submenu_Index = 0;
    }

    private void ShowHideMenus_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Point P = new Point(MainMenu.Location.X, MainMenu.Location.Y);
        Size S = new Size(MainMenu.Size.Width, MainMenu.Size.Height);
        if (Go_to == At.Left)
        {
            P = new Point(P.X - 30, P.Y);
            S = new Size(S.Width + 30, S.Height);
            if (P.X == 0)
            {
                Submenus[Submenu_Index].Visible = true;
                ShowHideMenus.Enabled = false;
                Current = Go_to;
            }
        }
        if (Go_to == At.Right)
        {
            P = new Point(P.X + 30, P.Y);
            S = new Size(S.Width - 30, S.Height);
            if (P.X == 930)
            {
                ShowHideMenus.Enabled = false;
                Current = Go_to;
            }
        }
        Reposition_Menu(P, S);
    }

    void Reposition_Menu(Point P, Size S)
    {
        MainMenu.Location = P;
        MainMenu.Size = S;
    }
```